# second image in treeview not refresh tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a problem when add one image to treeview from def

**case one - it is OK**

```
import tkinter
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import ttk    
window = tkinter.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(window)
tree["columns"]="one"
tree.heading("#0",text="Item",anchor=tkinter.W)
tree.heading("one", text="Detections",anchor=tkinter.W)
style = ttk.Style(window)
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=50)
tree.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tkinter.N)
img = PIL.Image.open("1.jpg")
img = img.resize((10, 10))                
img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
tree.insert('', 'end', text="predict", image=img, value=("title"))
```

**case two - not work**

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(window)
tree["columns"]="one"
tree.heading("#0",text="Item",anchor=tkinter.W)
tree.heading("one", text="Detections",anchor=tkinter.W)
style = ttk.Style(window)
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=50)
tree.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tkinter.N)
#img = PIL.Image.open("2.jpg")
#img = img.resize((10, 10))                
#img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
#tree.insert('', 'end', text="predict", image=img, value=("title"))

def snapshot():
    img = PIL.Image.open("2.jpg")
    img = img.resize((10, 10))
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    tree.insert('', 'end', text="predict2", image=img, value=("title2"))

btn_snapshot=tkinter.Button(window, text="Snapshot", width=50, command=snapshot)    
btn_snapshot.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Then, the problem is it when add image from def.... i can add item but the image isn't visible

any idea?

Comment: In case you have more than 1 image - append them to a list outside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guy, copy the solutions for others people.
@henry Yik, you are right is important keep all image in a list outside of the function

```
list_img = []
def snapshot():
    img = PIL.Image.open("frame-01-07-2019-22-02-38.jpg")
    img = img.resize((10, 10))
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    list_img.append(img)    
    tree.insert('', 'end', text="predict2", image=list_img[len(list_img)-1], value=("title2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very common question. You have to keep an image reference.

```
def snapshot():
    img = PIL.Image.open("2.jpg")
    img = img.resize((10, 10))
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    tree.img2dotjpg = img # store the reference
    tree.insert('', 'end', text="predict2", image=img, value=("title2"))
```